# XLSX to CSV or .txt "assertion failed" error

Tags: excel, gnumeric, ssconvert

I am attempting to convert an Excel file (test.xlsx, created in Office Professional Plus 2013) into either CSV or TXT format using SSCONVERT.

Using the command line, with and without identifying the importer (Gnumeric_Excel:excel_xml).

In either case, `ssconvert` fails with a message:

> ** (ssconvert:21953): CRITICAL **: wb_view_save_as: assertion 'IS_WORKBOOK_VIEW (wbv)' failed
>   ** (ssconvert:21953): CRITICAL **: wb_view_workbook: assertion 'IS_WORKBOOK_VIEW (wbv)' failed
>   (ssconvert:21953): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

No output file is generated.

I cannot find any information on the cause of this error.  A reading of the error would lead me to believe that `ssconvert` isn't believing the file is an .xlsx, but it is.

I've tried various input files with the same issue.

XLS conversions work correctly, however, as my provided file is sent in XLSX, that doesn't help solve my problem.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with following string "E Unsupported file format". In my case, I think error is coming because CSV contains Hindi fonts. Is there anyone who can provide solution for the same ?